# Solve overfull \hbox in equation's case

Tags: equations

I have just started LaTeX so this may be a silly question, but I am getting a warning "Overfull \hbox(---pt too wide) detected" and the compiled pdf shows this text "if the sum of edge densities in the patch (x', y') is greater than threshold" (line 3 in the code) in a single line and this line is going out of bounds. Ideally that line should've been printed in two lines. I have tried linebreak but that doesn't work here. How to correct this?

```
\begin{equation}
I^p(x',y') = \left\{\begin{array}{rl}
    1 & \text{if the sum of edge densities in the patch (x', y') is greater than threshold}\\
    0 & \text{otherwise}\\
    \end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
```

Comment: you just post a fragment that makes it hard for people to test and hard to suggest changes, In particualar the fragment gives no indication on how wide your text is so if we make a test document it may or may not be overfull depending on what we guess for font size and page size {but you can use a `\parbox` instead of `\text` if you need line breaks.

Comment: Also, is there a reason to emulate `cases` with `array`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't break lines in `\text`, but you can use a `\parbox`; adjust the width to suit.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for mock text

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[3]
\begin{equation}
I^p(x',y') =
\begin{cases}
  1 & \parbox[t]{.5\textwidth}{\raggedright
        if the sum of edge densities in the patch
        $(x', y')$ is greater than threshold
      }\\[4ex]
  0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With `mathtools` and `stackengine`, you have a very simple code. The `cases*` takes care of the left brace and the second column of the environment automatically leaves math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools, stackengine}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\def\stackalignment{l}
I^p(x',y') =\begin{cases*}
    1 & \stackunder{if the sum of edge densities in the patch}{$(x', y')$ is greater than threshold} \\
    0 & otherwise\\
    \end{cases*}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]